# How to resolve this warning: : taking address of temporary

Tags: c++, memory, warnings

```
case CSchemaType::m_Duration:
   return &operator CSchemaTypeCalendar::CDuration() != NULL;
```

in the above line How to resolve this warning: : taking address of temporary

Comment: Well, don't return the address of a temporary. More real code needed to understand the real problem and offer fixes.

Comment: You provide even less context here than you did on IRC. And already there we told you that you should not take the address of a temporary, and that wanting to check the address of a temporary against NULL does even make less sense, so you need to tell what your intention with that line of code is.

Comment: To resolve the compiler warning: Remove the line.

Comment: Replace the line with `return true;`.

Answer (score 0):

If your want the address of the method `operator CDuration`, omit the parentheses.

Comment: do you really think he wants to compare that address against NULL?

Comment: Well, yes. `&` (address-of) has higher precedence than `!=`, right? PS: Obviously, it does not make sense to compare the address of a temporary with NULL, though. But who am I to question the intentions of the OP. This at least answers his question ;)

Comment: The precedence is `(& (operator T())) != NULL`

Comment: I tried both the above suggestions by omiting () and adding paranthesis as mnetioned above but it seems warning is still persists. I n windows it is showing as warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue

Comment: @Sudhakar: What do you actually want? Maybe remove just the `&`-Operator, as suggested by all those comments before. Or just `return true`. What do you want?!

Comment: i just want to eliminate the comment warning: : taking address of temporary in the above line. For that I want to change in logic in the above line mentioned but not functionality. sort of rearranging the line of code

Comment: @Sudhakar But that line of code does not make any sense, the warning is there for a reason. We can only guess what you want to achieve. If it is meant exactly as it is written there, the only real solution is to `return true` as stated by @Mankarse -- that's not a joke, but exactly what this line should currently compile to.